# Insert values at a specific location for each time series of pixels using Numpy Array

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have a 3-dimensional Numpy Array. It is daily data of a year and 1-degree pixels of the globe, resulting in a shape of (365, 180, 360).

Now, you want to insert a value of 16th January to its position, so that each time series becomes:

...val_0114, val_0115, val_0116, val_0116, val_0117, val_0118, ...

I could do it like:

```
arr_new = np.empty((arr_old.shape[0], 180, 360)) * np.nan
for _lat in range(arr_new.shape[1]):
    for _lon in range(arr_new.shape[2]):
        arr_new[:, _lat, _lon] = np.insert(arr_old, 15, arr_old[15, _lat, _lon], axis=0)
```

But I would like to find a more fancy way without the loop.

Comment: are you sure you want to insert? your data has already the good shape and `insert` changes the shape

Comment: yes, the desired shape is 366*180*360

Comment: ok thanks. and you want to make the insert in the old data?

Comment: Yes. For example, if the old data is [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] then I want to get something like [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5]

Answer (score 0):

In numpy you are allowed to directly reference a matrix. This is similar to when you work with multi-dimensional lists:

```
# If you want to place the same temperature in the whole world/pixels
arr_old[16] = 15
# If you want to place the same temperature in a certain place the whole year
arr_old[:][lat][lon]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and congrat, the first contribution. I want to insert the value, so the shape will be changed to 366*180*360. Would, nevertheless, your answer work?

Comment: From my test, you almost had it. Use only the numpy insert like this:
`a = np.insert(a,0,np.nan,axis=0)` where you use the axis to define which part of the array you want (time,y,x), that 0 is to choose the starting point in which it adds the new values and the np.nan is the value to add. Hope it makes sense now.

Comment: Yes, that is what I found. The problem is that I need to apply it to all pixels. This is why I used the loop. Now I want to find a way to apply it to all pixels without a loop.